# How to get audio from AppleWatch like Shazam does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, shazam

Recently I have realized that Shazam has developed an AppleWatch application but in many questions and answers in StackOverflow, we have talked about the no possibility of recording audio directly from your watch.

Does a new way exist to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Shazam app simply activates the app on your phone. The WatchKit SDK doesn't allow access to the mic. They mention this in their marketing materials and such.